# $g(z) = f(|z|)$ is not holomorphic for a non constant function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant function. Define $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$g(z) = f(|z|).$ Then I want to show that g is not holomorphic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you any ideas what sort of theorems may be useful here?

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Maybe Liouville's theorem is useful.

Comment: Only if $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Please give some hint.

Answer (score 4):

It follows directly from the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Remember that a function $f(z=x+iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ is holomorphic iff

$$\partial_x u = \partial_y v \\
\partial_y u = -\partial_x v$$

In this cases $u$ and $v$ are functions depending only on $|z|$. If you use the chain rule and $\partial_x |z| = x/|z|$, $\partial_y |z|=y/|z|$, then the above equations can be used to get

$$v'(|z|)\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)=0$$

whenever $x, y\neq 0$. But this equation implies that $v'=0$ and $v$ is constant. Put that again in the CR equations to get $u$ is constant.

So the only holomorphic functions of the form you have specified are constant ones.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are getting that expression $v^{'}(|z|)=..$

Comment: @learnmore The two CR equations become $x/|z|\ u'(|z|) = y/|z|\ v'(z)$ and $y|z|\ u'(z)=-x/|z|\ v'(|z|)$. If $x\neq0$ you can get $u' = y/x\ v'$ from the first equation, put this into the second equation to get $y^2/(x|z|)\ v' = - x/|z|\ v'$. This can then be seen to be the same as the expression given.